# What is the difference between "my" and "our" in terms of symbolic references?

Tags: perl

Our:

```
our $ref = "test";
my $var = "ref";
print "$$var";   #the output will be test
```

My:

```
my $ref = "test";
my $var = "ref";
print "$$var\n"; #the output is blank
```

Comment: The referenced question is different in that it is a general question about lexical and package variables. This question asks specifically about soft references.

Comment: This poorly titled question about soft references is not answered by the above referenced question.  Answer:  Soft References always reference a variable in a Package/Global namespace.  Lexical (my) variables need not apply.  Soft References are also considered harmful and are blocked by `use strict vars`.  Most times you are tempted to use Soft References you should consider using a hash instead.

Comment: Ok, the question is different and I guess therefore I MIGHT support reopening. The problem is that this is generally seen as bad form, the OP should not be attempting this (should be using strict) until (s)he can answer this question IMO.

Comment: Bad form:  Reopening a question or closing it as a pseudo-duplicate?

Comment: Your question answers your question perfectly.

Comment: @tjd, sorry my comment was badly phrased. Symbolic references are considered bad form. Rather than teach the OP to shoot him/herself in the foot, I advocate leaving this question closed. People who are likely to benefit from symbolic references already know how to appropriately use package variables.

Comment: @JoelBerger: That a construct is bad practice is a dreadful reason to close a question in the first place, and hence a dreadful reason not to reopen it. The correct answer should be given with a proviso, and that cannot be done for a closed question.

Comment: @Borodin, agreed. I would not now vote to close it, now that we have figured out what the question was intended to ask. As is I'm not inclined to reopen it. If it is reopened, so be it.

Comment: @JoelBerger: That makes little sense. Should this question be open or closed?

Comment: My point about the validity of the question is in fact moot. It should be closed as an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338369/why-cant-i-use-a-perl-variables-value-to-access-a-lexical-variable-name and several others.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) will set up a package variable, while [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) sets up a lexical variable.

What that means is that variables declared with [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) can be accessed outside of the current scope.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
{
  our $g = 5;
}
{
  print our($g), "\n";
}
```

```
5
```

While lexical variables exist only in a given scope.

```
{
  # stored in this block
  my $l = 5;
  {
    # accessible from this block
    print $l, "\n";
    $l = 6;

    # new variable stored in this lower block
    my $l = 7;
  }
  print $l, "\n";
}
{
  # yet another new variable
  print my($l), "\n";
}
```

```
5
6
Use of uninitialized value $a in print at -e line 1.
```

---

When you were trying to access `$$var` you were using a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references); which only work on package/global variables:

```
our $g = 5;

my $symbolic_ref = 'g';

{
  no strict 'refs';
  # these are symbolic refs
  print $$symbolic_ref, "\n";
  print ${ *{$symbolic_ref} }, "\n";
  print ${ *{$symbolic_ref}{SCALAR} }, "\n";
}

# access it through the magic %:: variable
print ${ $::{$symbolic_ref} }, "\n";
print ${ $main::{$symbolic_ref} }, "\n";
```

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

---

That is opposed to [regular references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).

```
my $v = 5;

my $ref = \$v;

print $$ref, "\n";
print ${ $ref }, "\n";
```

```
5
5
```

---

There is rarely any reason to use a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references).